# Where to initialize System Media Player

Tags: media, cobalt

We want to port cobalt release 11 to our media player, but we don't know where to initialize the media player in Cobalt.

I wonder if it is a good place to call the media framework initialization in createWebMediaPlayer (cobalt/media/media_module_starboard.cc).

```
 scoped_ptr<WebMediaPlayer>CreateWebMediaPlayer(WebMediaPlayerClient *client) OVERRIDE {
   ...
   XXX_mediaplayer_initialize(); <<<< call our media player initialization

   #if defined(COBALT_MEDIA_SOURCE_2016)
     SbWindow window = kSbWindowInvalid;
     if (system_window_) {
       window = system_window_->GetSbWindow();
     }
   ...
 }
```

Since our media player initialization takes more than 1 sec, it may cause Youtube Movie begins to play slowly > 1sec.

Please advise any suitable place to initialize system media framework in Cobalt release 11.

Answer (score 0):

Does this need to be called only once during system startup or every time a video is going to be played?

For the first case, you can put it into your Starboard Application initialization code.  For the second case, you may still "pre-warm" it in your Starboard Application code.

You should always avoid modifying Cobalt code directly.